# JavaScript error without using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html

I'm not using any JS code, but the console gives me the error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Here is my html code

```
<div id="navbar">
<div class="width2">
    <div class="navbarchild right">
        <div class="NBsearch right">
            <input type="text" placeholder="search" />
        </div>
        <div class="NBuser right">
            <div class="NBpicture left">
            </div>
            <div class="NBreputation left">
            </div>
            <div class="NBbadge left">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="navbarchild left">
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

*I tried to see where the problem come from,and it seems that it comes from

```
<input type="text" placeholder="search" />
```

because when I delete this line the error don't appear.

Comment: You probably have some javascript plugin on website that is causing the error.

Comment: Some JavaScript is running, are you sure you're not loading __any__ JavaScript at all?

Comment: you are using jquery.placeholder.js or something like it?

Comment: Try disabling your extensions and try again

Comment: Some Javascript is definitely being executed. You can check it out in the Javascript console of Chrome Developer Tools or Firebug. If you show us *all* of your code, we might be able to find the culprit for you.

Comment: your code works fine for me

Comment: @toby I disabled all my extensions and no error appeared. Thank you. But how could an extension affect a simple html code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Disable your extensions one by one from [chrome://extensions](http://chrome://extensions/) (i'm supposing you're using chrome, for FF check this [link](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/disable-or-remove-add-ons))  and see which one causes the problem there's no point in disabling all of them.

And as an answer to you're question about how a can an extension do that the simple answer is that it's just javascript, html and css injected into you page(not really experienced in this field).

For more information about chrome extensions check [here](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions)

Answer (score 0):

To know which Extension was loaded on your page you can go (when extensions are activated) in the Dev Tool (F12) -> Source -> Content scripts.
This is for Chrome.